# How to create shared content for every Vuejs View?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am learning Vuejs and trying to clone the [Remotive.io](https://remotive.io/remote-jobs) website using their API.

First of all, I am trying to clone UI and create some basic stylesheet.

My architecture is like that :

I have components, router and views, and also App.vue where I put my navigation bar with simple router navigation. Also in the App.vue I want to add everything, which will be the same on every page.

As you can see [Remotive.io](https://remotive.io/) has this little picture which is shared on every page, to just copy img tag and put this on every my Vue Views I think is a stupid thing and it's not relevant.

My understanding of how Vuejs works is that : 
App.vue is shared Vue root content which will be loaded on every page. So if I want to make some static image, which I want to load on every view as a navigation bar, I need to put it into my App.vue file.

So this is my App.vue file

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="nav">
      <nav> 
          <img src="https://blog.remotive.io/content/images/2017/03/logo-remotive-black-1.png" alt="">
          <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
          <router-link to="/about">About</router-link> |
          <router-link to="/contact">Contact</router-link>
      </nav> 
    </div>
    <router-view />

    <div class="remotiveImage">
        <img src="https://remotive.io/remotive_website_static_pages/static/src/img/illustrations/1x/jobs.png" alt="">

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
  .nav img {
    width: 40%;
    height:auto;
  }

  .nav {
        display:flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        min-height: 50px;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px rgba(2,2,2,.2);
  }

  .remotiveImage {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
</style>
```

And this is my homepage view file

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <div class="mainText">
      <h1> Find the Best Remote Job </h1>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
.remotiveImage {
  margin-top:20px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.mainText {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
</style>
```

And the website looks like this [image]

I don't understand why the text content, which is in my view is top of the picture, which is in the App.vue ?

What am I doing wrong? 
Should not App.vue content must be on the top for every page?

If I would add any component or any HTML, it always is on the top of this picture, which is loading in App.vue

I am very beginner in front-end and very beginner in Vue, so any help and advice will be appreciated and helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you app.vue template to look like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="nav">
      <nav> 
          <img src="https://blog.remotive.io/content/images/2017/03/logo-remotive-black-1.png" alt="">
          <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
          <router-link to="/about">About</router-link> |
          <router-link to="/contact">Contact</router-link>
      </nav> 
    </div>

    <div class="remotiveImage">
        <img src="https://remotive.io/remotive_website_static_pages/static/src/img/illustrations/1x/jobs.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>
```

Basically, the content being rendered by your router (the text-containg component in question) will be rendered at this line:

```
<router-view />
```

So if you want your app.vue content (the image) to appear above it, simply make sure it is sitting about the `router-view`!

App.vue essentially acts as a wrapper around the router content, as opposed to just rendering before or after that content

Comment: Excellent it worked. Now I understood what was the trick. Thank you very much